# Виды очереди по наличию людей

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как с помощью понятий, выражений отличить очередь, формирующуюся в виде списка (в частности, электронную) и очередь непосредственно расположенных рядом людей (чаще всего согласно этому предварительному списку).

Как я понимаю, слово "живая" означает отсутствие официального списка, заменяемого временным списком, порядком, но не отражает различия между "предварительной" и "действующей". Какие же понятия отражают?

Пример. В муз. академии формируется очередь за классом. Один человек стоит первым и составляет свой список. К нему подходят люди, вносят свои имена. Далее, через 1-2 часа все эти люди собираются и входят по очереди вносить свои имена уже в "официальный список".

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, уже давно вошло в обиход выражение "очередь по предварительной записи", а ему противостоит "живая очередь".

**Живая** очередь - когда люди приходят и занимают очередь по времени прихода, а **предварительная запись** - или электронная очередь, или запись по телефону.

Всё чаще предварительную запись называют **электронной,** потому что теперь очередь **везде формируется в электронном виде**: если Вы записались дома через онлайн-регистратуру, позвонили в регистратуру и Вас записали, пришли в регистратуру - Вас записали всё в ту же электронную очередь, она одна, живая очередь теперь редкость, без записи можно попасть на приём только в образовавшееся у врача свободное время и только по согласованию с самим доктором.

Госуслуги тоже оказываются по электронной очереди.

> После завершения онлайн-бронирования очереди, в указанном отделе НАО
>   ГК "Правительство для граждан" и в выбранное время необходимо получить
>   талон **электронной очереди** через терминал выдачи талонов, нажав на
>   кнопку «Бронирование». Указав ИИН, терминал выдаст талон электронной
>   очереди, по которому вас примут в назначенном окне в течение 30 минут.

http://egov.kz/cms/ru/services/psc_bron

Answer (score 0):

Упреждающий список.

> упреждать упреждать несов. перех. разг. 1. Делать что-либо раньше кого-либо или чего-либо; опережать, обгонять. 2. Извещать заранее; предупреждать. (Толковый словарь Ефремовой).

Answer (score 0):

- очередь по списку - когда список определяет очередность. а запись в список может осуществляться по разному, хоть через интернет.
- очередь перед пунктом - когда очередь образовалось естественным образом из-за того что пункт не успевает принять сразу.

живая очередь просто означает что люди в очереди находятся перед пунктом, но это вовсе не исключает списка. поэтому я бы не стал использовать эту фразу.